# Show li elements one below each other

Tags: html, css

I have two `ul` elements and each `ul` element has multiple `li` elements. I want the first `li` element of the second `ul` exactly below the first `li` element of the first `ul`. Similarly, the second `li` element of both the `ul` should be exactly one below the other.

Here is the demo
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d853fhko/1/)

If there is extra `li` element, I want it to be in the next line instead of having it in the same line with overflow (For example fourth `li` element in each `ul`)

I am applying `white-space: nowrap;` as I don't want the `li` element to break into the next line.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Flexbox to achieve this easily.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}

ul:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1 33%;
  border: 1px green solid;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a632pxhf/1/

Comment: In your fiddle `li` element with text `Fourth li of second ul element` is splitting into next line. Actually I want whole `li` element into the next line if there is not enough space

Comment: Please check now. It really come down to your content. At some point columns are gonna go out of alignment i.e. li's of ul's. You could use media query to change flex % thereby increasing the % to 50% on medium screens and flex: 1 on mobile screens.